# Echo directory after change?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

*(Since I couldn't find an explicit answer to this anywhere and I find it useful, I though I would add it to SO.  Better alternatives welcome.)*

In Bash, how do you alias `cd` to echo the new working directory after a change?  Like this:

```
$ pwd
/some/directory
$ cd newness
/some/directory/newness
$
```

Something simple like `alias cd='cd "$@" && pwd'` doesn't work.  For some reason, Bash responds as though you used `cd -` and returns to `$OLDPWD` and you get caught in a loop.  I don't understand this behavior.

Comment: Aliases don't know about `"$@"` or parameters in general. This is one of the many reasons to use a function instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, you need to do this through a function:

```
function mycd() {
  cd "$@" && pwd
}
alias cd=mycd
```

However, if you use `cd -` you wind up printing the directory twice, so this is more robust:

```
function mycd() {
  if [ "$1" == "-" ]; then
    cd "$@"
  else
    cd "$@" && pwd
  fi
}
alias cd=mycd
```

I may be missing some edge cases, like `cd -P -` and `cd -L -`, though I don't know if those even make sense.

*(See Adrian Frühwirth's answer below for the reason why a simple alias doesn't work and why I feel dumb now.)*

Answer (score 0):

The alias doesn't work because aliases don't support arguments, so you cannot chain commands that require parameters. Because of this `cd "$@"` doesn't make sense in the context of an alias and whatever argument you supply to an alias just gets appended:

```
$ alias foo='echo "[$@]" && echo'
$ foo bar
[]
bar
```

Obviously, that's not what you want and exactly why you need to resort to a function.

Comment: Oh, wow. It _appends_ only. That explains other problems I've run into.  Thanks.